# RazorEngine 3.6.3 cannot convert from 'string' to 'RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplateKey

Tags: asp.net, razorengine

I have a problem with RazorEngine version 3.6.3
RazorEngine cannot convert from 'string' to 'RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplateKey

My code is below:

```
        var templateServiceConfiguration = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
        templateServiceConfiguration.Namespaces.Add("System.Configuration");

        var body = string.Empty;

        using (var service = RazorEngineService.Create(templateServiceConfiguration))
        {
            body = service.RunCompile(emailTemplate.Body, emailTemplate.UniqueName, model: _model, modelType: null, viewBag: null);
        }
```

So this method service.RunCompile( what as first parameter ITemplateKey, but there also overloads of this method that must support my version.

Please, help.

Comment: I've had similar problems navigating the large number of overrides to RunCompile(). It's worth putting the argument names on *all* of your parameters to see which might be incorrectly lined up.

Comment: Boggin, please provide more info about your issue if you want help.

Comment: it was rather that this was how I found my problem, by specifying each of the optional argument names as there are a lot of similar overrides, and I thought it would be useful to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using this RazorEngineServiceExtensions.RunCompile(service, emailTemplate.Body, emailTemplate.UniqueName, modelType: null, model: _model);

Answer (score 6):

This co-incidently enabled me to solve my different but similar problem. Thanks!

I was getting basically the same error message except while using Engine.Razor.RunCompile as below:

```
Engine.Razor.RunCompile("templateid", templateHtml, null, new { Name = "World" });
```

Where the documentation says you must only include the RazorEngine.Templating namespace, I needed to include both RazorEngine and RazorEngine.Templating.

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating;
```